# Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 7.1.2 requires SSL/TLS - Python 3.x & OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I am trying to install Python 3.5.1 according to these instructions:

http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2014/08/installing-another-python-version-into-virtualenv/

I have: OS X 10.11.3, no Homebrew. Xcode is installed. Xcode Command Line Tools are installed.

Everything goes well until `make install` has run for a while. Then it quits with this:

```
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
        case upgrade in \
            upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
            install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
        esac; \
         ./python.exe -E -m ensurepip \
            $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
    fi
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 7.1.2 requires SSL/TLS
```

I have been searching for a long time and all I can find are instructions for Homebrew or for Apache or other servers. I understand that I've got to get SSL/TLS on my system, but I've had no luck.

The biggest reason I don't want Homebrew is that I want non-CS students to follow the same procedure, and I don't want them to install Homebrew.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It gives you an error because it misses *OpenSSL*. However Apple no longer provides *OpenSSL* in Xcode, so you need to manually install. The simplest approach is to use the [Homebrew package manager](http://brew.sh/), install the required package, and then include the *OpenSSL* libs:

```
export CPPFLAGS="${CPPFLAGS} -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include"
export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib"
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying not to install Homebrew, but nothing else worked. I finally used: 
`brew install openssl`
`brew link --overwrite --dry-run openssl`
`brew link --force openssl`

Comment: thanks to your breadcrumb I was able to install python 3.9 after following these instructions https://cloudwafer.com/blog/installing-openssl-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/