# Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip requires SSL/TLS - Python 3.4.X with pyenv on OS X

Tags: macos, openssl, python-3.4, pyenv

I am trying to install python version 3.4.10 via pyenv but I get the error `Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 9.0.1 requires SSL/TLS`. For python versions after 3.4.10 (e.g.: 3.5.9), it did succeed however. 
I tried following the instructions both on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280956/ignoring-ensurepip-failure-pip-7-1-2-requires-ssl-tls-python-3-x-os-x) and on [the official pyenv Common Build page](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/common-build-problems) and it always returned the following error message:

```
Last 10 log lines:
(cd ~/.pyenv/versions/3.4.10/share/man/man1; ln -s python3.4.1 python3.1)
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
                case upgrade in \
                        upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
                        install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
                esac; \
                 ./python.exe -E -m ensurepip \
                        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
        fi
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 9.0.1 requires SSL/TLS
```

Answer (score 4):

I came across [this post](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/950#issuecomment-567113563) which specified uninstalling `OpenSSL v1.1` and caused `pyenv` to install the correct version (1.0.2) of OpenSSL to compile python with.

The solution that worked for me was:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl@1.1
pyenv install 3.4.10
```

**Attention**: This may cause some libraries to break that depend on `OpenSSL`, so either re-install the latest version afterwards using `brew install openssl` or execute the following to have version `1.0.0` via brew:

```
 brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```